# Why does row-fluid:before and row-fluid:after have a height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[On my website (click)](http://onceridden.demomycms.co.uk/), one of many on which I've used twitter-bootstrap v2.3.2, for some reason the `row-fluid:before`, `row-fluid:after`, `clearfix:before` and `clearfix:after` content all have a width of 9px and a height of 8px.

No other sites have this issue and the height ignores `height: 0 !important` and the only thing that can get rid of it is to remove the content entirely, which breaks the clearfix.

What is causing this? How can I get rid of it? I can't find anything on Google remotely related to this and it's been pissing me off all day!

I can't replicated this issue, I've tried copying a row and all it's content into jsfiddle, then link to every style sheet the website has included and it's fine, the :before content has no height and 1px width, the same as every other site I have.

**After eliminating css files by commenting them out I've found out it's something to do with main.css.**

Picture of the bug occurring in Chrome (replicable in Firefox too).
[image: Picture of this occurring in Chrome (replicable in Firefox too)]

Comment: Well... I don't see it either... Is it a specific `row-fluid` div or every one?

Comment: Every single row-fluid and clearfix has this. I've just removed all css files bar the basic bootstrap and that got rid of the issue, so going to try and isolate which file is causing the issue.

Comment: On that site I see `.row-fluid:before, .row-fluid:after` has specifcally set `height: 0 !important;`

Comment: I've checked it in dev tools, they all have a height of 0... How do you see it has a 9px width and 8px height? Do you see by looking at it that there is some extra margin, or do you see it in your dev tools somehow?

Comment: Oh wait, I see what you mean now. It's because after and before are set to `display: table`

Comment: I've added a screen shot of what I get. @DavidG the `height: 0 !important` I added to try and get around this issue, it did nothing. The `display: table` is part of the default bootstrap code that works fine on every other site I have.

Comment: Aah now I see it as well, but not with EVERY div. Only the decendants of a div with class `no-line-height` (which have the rule `line-height: normal`) have this issue.

Comment: I tried removing `.no-line-height` from the css, no effect.

Comment: Got the specific line - `.home-content { border-spacing: 4px }` It's applying a border spacing to all tables inside `.home-content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is in `main.css`, you have some `border-spacing` applied, remove this and it goes away:

```
.home-content {
     border-spacing: 4px;
}
```

Comment: I've added `.home-content * {border-spacing: 0px;}`, I got it just about the same time you did. Thank you for your help :).